# Extract and plot XML data using python

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to analyze my XML file, I would like to get data X Y Z for advanced analysis later and then plot all values.
Here the XML files looks like:

```
      <UserPosition>
      <X>-12.2934008394709</X>
      <Y>52.488259963403273</Y>
      <Z>-0.92276278637695341</Z>
      </UserPosition>
```

this is my code :

```
  from lxml import etree
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  import numpy as np
  # Read xml files
  PostX = []
  PostY= []
  Thikness = []
  tree = etree.parse("XMLFILE.xml")
  for UserPosition in 
  tree.xpath("/cResult/measure/lMeasuredItem/cMeasureItem/UserPosition/X"):

  PostX.append(UserPosition.text)


  print PostX
```

I'm getting this ! :

['-12.2934008394709', '-9.1133008238197366', '-5.9329608027622784', '-2.7523007917339029',

Any help to get a proper values for analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any reason you cant change

```
PostX.append(UserPosition.text)
```

to

```
PostX.append(float(UserPosition.text))
```

Otherwise, it would be helpful to see how it is all your x, y and z values (or certainly more of them) are structured in this .xml file.

Comment: I'm able now to plot my data

Comment: @Sater that’s great! If this helped for you, can you accept this as an answer

Comment: if i have one value as <cMeasureItem IsTopCamera="true" dMeasuredThicknesses0="1984.2276044015287" how to get thickness in plot?

Comment: I'm using his function                                                                                  Thickness =  cMeasureItem.get("dMeasuredThicknesses0") I'm getting only the first value not all the file values!! can you help

Comment: @Sater Sure! Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53240127/read-an-xml-element-using-python/53240704#53240704) I replied to the other day, and hopefully that will point you in the right direction. If it helps please up vote it.